# Threadsafe name reservation on appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, thread-safety, google-cloud-datastore

I'm creating and editing groups.  I need to check to see if a group name is already in use before creating a new group with that name or changing an existing group name to that name.

The problem is that two parallel threads could both check for the group name at the same time, and then each thread could go ahead and add its own group.  Duplicate names!

I don't think I can use the built-in transactions, because these groups should be in different entity groups and the name is not part of the key.  What can I do?

Would it make sense to make a sort of index entity that uses the group name in the key, so that I can do an ancestor query to fetch and create the name atomically?  Success creating the index entity would serve as permission for the non-transactional code to execute.  I would hope for a simpler solution that doesn't require a whole new type of entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An 'index entity' as you describe is a standard approach to this, though I don't know what you mean about using an ancestor query - the index entity should neither be a child of any other entity, nor have any children.

Bear in mind the transactional implications of doing this: unexpected failures can lead to names that are reserved but not used.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a [Memcache](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/overview.html) solution instead of a new entity?  You'd probably have to periodically clear it out.

Answer (score 0):

Is there no way to use the group name (or a hash based on the name) as the key?  Because that + group.get_or_insert(group_name) would basically solve your problems. That method automatically runs in a transaction and either creates or retrieves an entity with that key_name.

Comment: I'm pretty entrenched using `Long` ids to refer to entities on the client side.  Switching is an option, of course, and might be easier (and more bug-resistant) than my index entity solution.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Riley `hashlib.sha256('my group name').hexdigest()` or `hashlib.sha256('my group name').digest().encode('base64')` would give you hashes that could be used as keys, and could be used on the client side (although they would ugly-up your URLs).

Comment: Even better: `base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hashlib.sha256('my group name').digest()).rstrip('=')`

Answer (score 0):

Do you guys really think transactions can serve as thread locks? No.

Furthermore, the best approach to avoid race conditions under an environment of parallel computing is, though, to avoid conflicting writes. That is, revise your structure, delay and gather the group-name writes into a single thread. Yes it's not in real time, but I doubt if you really need a real time group name generation. Remember, use asynchrony everywhere and embrace inconsistency if you want more than a toy system.